# zabbix Trigger with user macros

Tags: zabbix

I need help around triggers and using user macros in them.  Using zabbix 3.4. I have a host and it has macro called `'{$CLASS_A}'`

I want to setup a Trigger that goes off when `{$CLASS_A} = "HUGE"` and free memory is less the 5G.

```
{my_test_server.vm.memory.size[available].last()}<5G
```

Can I not just do:

```
{$CLASS_A} = "HUGE" AND {my_test_server.vm.memory.size[available].last()}<5G
```

I can not see what I should be doing to get this to work. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The "and" operator is case-sensitive and should be lowercase.

The macro usage is incorrect as well: you can use a macro on the right portion of the expression (see [here](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/macros/usermacros#examples) for more), like:

```
{ca_001:system.cpu.load[,avg1].last()}>{$MAX_CPULOAD}
```

You can modify your current trigger to:

```
{my_test_template:vm.memory.size[available].last()}<{$MAX_MEMORY}
```

then define `{$MAX_MEMORY}` both on the template and the host: the template macro value will act as default and you can ovverride it with a host macro.